# Как называется этот раздел программирования на C#

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер

Здравствуй ХешКод, помогите составить запрос для Яндекса, я хочу научится делать программы типа Клиент-Сервер. А то посмотрел на работы, Клиент-Сервера такая интересная вещь, хочу научится. Но вот как называется этот раздел правильно не знаю.

Comment: вы имеете ввиду WCF?

Comment: Наверно так.

Answer (score 3):

раздел называется так: "Г.Шилдт C# 4.0 Полное руководство", если бы вы удосужились хоть капельку вашего бесценного времени уделить на изучение языка C# и хотя бы для начало прочтения данной книги, то вопросов бы таких не задавали. А так, складывается ощущение, что вы хотите формашлепством заниматься.

Comment: Я до этого времени изучал C# по видео-урокам....

Comment: а... ну тогда все понятно... видео уроки - ЗЛО! по ним вы ничему не научитесь это давно уже всем известный факт.Одно дело смотреть виде-уроки, когда у тебя за спиной есть какая то база знаний и ты смотришь т.к. не понял какой то мелочи, и совсем другое дело, это когда у тебя вообще нет никаких знаний, и ты сидишь и тупо переключаешь окошки, то виде, то код, переписывая все 1 в 1.

Comment: Ага, Вы что думаете что я учусь по этим Ютубовским роликам? Я купил хорошие и качественные видео-уроки от Георгия Могелашвили, там в начале урока идёт **теория**, а потом уже практика, и + домашнее задание и консультация в скайпе... так что уроки нормальные я по ним основу легко выучил.

Comment: я не хочу разводить тут флуд и что то вам доказывать, спросите у любого нормального программиста что он думает о видео уроках, я уверен на все 100% его ответ не особо будет отличаться от моего ) 
P.S. если бы уроки были нормальные, то вы бы не задавали такие глупые вопросы

Comment: @Angus123 Согласен на 100%, Георгий Могелашвили - самый известный и лучший преподаватель по `C#`.

Comment: Константин25, там рассказывают о базе языка C#, а не углублённо...

Comment: @Angus123, в гугле "C# connect socket" и читаете. Прямо сразу ссылка на класс Socket. 

Правда перед этим хорошо бы почитать про TCP/IP независимо от языка, а в хороших материалах на эту тему обязательно есть примеры (обычно на Си (без шарпа)). 

Вот с Си и Unix (если Вам **действительно интересно клиент-серверное программирование**) и начните.

Comment: @Котик я если честно впервые только что услышал)

Comment: @rasmisha Вы не поверите, но я тоже :)

Comment: Котик и расмиша, спасибо поржал )

Comment: Может быть Георгий Могелашвили скоро станет такой же знаменитостью как Фленов? 

А по существу - поддержу @avp. Перед тем как окунаться в опыты с сокетами будет крайне полезно изучить не привязанную к языку матчасть. Могу порекомендовать, например,  
[Протоколы TCP/IP. Практическое руководство](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1354276/).

Comment: Фленов??? ааа это тот, кто учит людей быдлокодить ?!

Comment: @Константин25, Фленов главным образом известен серией `%random_word% глазами хакера`. Радует [выдача гугла](http://www.google.ru/#q=Фленов) на этот счет )